# NSUserDefaults + NSMutableArray -> Storing 2 arrays and display in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have just implementet a bookmark/favorites function in my app, favorites from a `tableview`, with the following code, using `NSUserDefaults`. The cell has 2 labels, the name of the item and a price - stored in the Arrays - `theArray` and `thePriceArray` -> like this:

[image]

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_ListTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)     [[sender superview] superview]];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSMutableArray *OrderList = [[defaults objectForKey:ORDER_KEY] mutableCopy];
    if (!OrderList) OrderList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [OrderList addObject:[theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [OrderList addObject:[thePriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [defaults setObject:OrderList forKey:ORDER_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

I am now adding the two arrays  `theArray` & `thePriceArray`, to the `NSMutableArray`.I now  want to show these information (the information from the arraies) in another `tableview`. I do this like so:

In My `viewDidAppear`:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = kSettings;


    NSMutableArray *theOrderList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:ORDER_KEY]];
```

And to show the contents in the `tableview`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [theOrderList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TheTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [theOrderList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}
```

This is almost working as I want, the contents of `theArray` and `thePriceArray` is shown, but in a long list like so:

[image]

I want the "key and the value" to be in one cell, so the price and the item name in one cell (Hat - 30) and not seperate, how can I do that? I have tried to use a `NSDictionary`, but without luck and can I use `NSDictionary` for this?

Comment: You should consider writing a model class to hold such data. This will make your code much better to read & understand.

Comment: Hi Ravi, thank you for your input. I would consider that, would something like Core Data, be an option to store data like this? The data in the arrays, use fx. Core data instead of NSUserDefaults? Thank you.

Comment: @Seya : Do you get your Answer ?

Comment: Like in your case, `Product` could be a class and it's two attributes could be `productName` and `productPrice`. And when you add it to an array, then you won't have to maintain different arrays.

Comment: Thank you. I will strongly consider that. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two new arrays for favItem and favPrize. Just add your favorite Items to favItem Array and add favorite Prizes to favPrize Array. Now use these arrays to set the labels and detailLabels of your Tableview like :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [favItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [favPrize objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer too. I can't do the following, since I save these arrays contents, into a new array and retrieve this information in another class, with NSUserDefaults and inserting this data into the array "theOrderList". Thank you for your input though. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Keep both array `theArray` and `thePriceArray` `seperate` and use one as your main array for data source of tableView.

**Note** : add data from NSUserDefault to respective array.

Now method will be :

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [theArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TheTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubTile reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [thePriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I can't do the following, since I save these arrays contents, into a new array and retrieve this information in another class, with NSUserDefaults and inserting this data into the array "theOrderList". Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using the following code:

```
NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@    %@",[theOrderList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)],[theOrderList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)+1]
cell.textLabel.text = label;
```

And also change your `numberOfRowsInSection` like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [theOrderList count]/2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer and your input. I tried the following code, but the app crashes, saying: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack. Any way to fix this? :) thank you.

Comment: @Seya: still have issues ?

Comment: Hi Midhun, it seems to work now, but I don't think this is the right solution for my project. Since it need add up all the prices to a total price in the end and it dosen't seem to be possible with this method? Also when I delete the row, it is only the price, which get deleted and not the whole cell.Very clever work around though. Thank you for your help and input. It is appreciated.